# Inventory, OrderItems and Order

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

The problem I'm facing now is I have multiple Orders and each Order contains multiple items. Each Order has to link to a Client and Each item has to link to a Inventory Item.
Here's my Order Class

```
public class Order
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int TotalItems { get; set; }

        public DateTime DeliveryDate { get; set; }

        public string OrderNumber { get; set; }

        public int ClientId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ClientId")]
        public string DeliveryAddress { get; set; }

        public List<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
        public Client Clients { get; set; }
}
```

OrderItem Class

```
 public class OrderItem
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int OrderId{ get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("OrderId")]

        public int InventoryInfoId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("InventoryInfoId")]

        [Required]
        public string ItemCode { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public InventoryInfo InventoryInfo { get; set; }
        public Order Order { get; set; }
    }
```

Any idea of how I can link them?

***I think I have solved the above issues***

As soon as I process, the next problem pops out.

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.OrderNumber)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(m=> item.DeliveryAddress)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Convert.ToDateTime(item.DeliveryDate).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(m=>item.Client.ClientCode)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TotalItems)
        </td>
        <td>
            <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-success">Edit</a> 
            <a asp-controller="OrderItem" asp-action="OrderDetail" asp-route-id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-success">Details</a> 
            <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-success">Delete</a> 

        </td>
    </tr>
    }
```

This is my Orders Index page, when the details button is been clicked, the page should redirect to OrderItems page. However it doesnot.

```
@model List<IOSystem.Models.OrderItem>
 @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.ItemCode)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Quantity)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |

                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

And here is the error message.

InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[IOSystem.Models.Order]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[IOSystem.Models.OrderItem]'.

Forgot to add my controller

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("OrderDetail")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> OrderDetailPost(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            var orderItems = await _context.Orders.Include(s=>s.OrderItems).FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.OrderItemId == id);
            
            return View(orderItems);
        }
```

Comment: FYI you need to move `[ForeignKey("ClientId")]` above `public int ClientId`. it's currently marked `DeliveryAddress` as the FK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `InvalidOperationException` is saying you're passing a `List<Order>` but the model in your Razor page is a `List<OrderItem>`

In your controller code:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("OrderDetail")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> OrderDetailPost(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    var orderItems = await _context.Orders.Include(s=>s.OrderItems).FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.OrderItemId == id);
    
    return View(orderItems);
}
```

You're accessing `_context.Orders`, which is your `Orders` table. You're `.Include`-ing the `OrderItems` but you're returning your `Orders`.

Either pass back the `OrderItems` from `var orderItems = ...` or adjust your Razor page's Model to be a `List<Order>`.

If you want to select the `OrderItems` from your `Order` in the controller code, update your LINQ statement to:

```
var orderItems = (await _context.Order
    .Include(s => s.OrderItems)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.OrderItemId == id))
    .Select(x => x.OrderItems); // <-- grab just the OrderItems
```

Comment: Hi James I have tried the two method you mentioned. When I try to grab just the OrderItems, It returns that the Task<Order> does not contains a definition for 'Select'. While the other method changing the model to List<IOSystem.Models.Order>, definition of ItemCode is not in List<OrderItem>.

Comment: I've adjusted my LINQ statement to execute the `FirstOrDefaultAsync` in its own scope, then select afterwards. You can always grab the single order using your original LINQ statement, then on a separate line do `orderItems.Select(x => x.OrderItems);` to fetch them.

Comment: Hi James, the same error pops out again. Is is the same if I add a `.OrderItems` behind the `FirstOrDefaultAsync`?

Comment: @Bruce break it out into 2 lines. Select the order with your current query (from your post), then create a separate variable to `.Select(x => x.OrderItems)` and `return View(newVariable);`